# autoref to dmath (from breqn package) generates wrong link text

Tags: hyperref, luatex, breqn

In the following minimal example, what is wrong with my `dmath` equation?  Why does hyperref call it a Figure, while `autoref` gets the link text correct for an equation defined with `\begin{equation}`

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{multiplication}
2 * 1 = 2
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Something strange}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{dmath}\label{addition}
1 + 1 = 2
\end{dmath}

I want to talk about \autoref{addition}, not \autoref{fig}.

\begin{equation}
\label{subtraction}
2 - 1 = 1
\end{equation}

And \autoref{multiplication} is not very interesting.  Let me speak of \autoref{addition}.
\end{document}
```

The document has three hyperlinks to equations and one to the figure.  But the output says "Figure" three times and "Equation" only once.  All the links to breqn environments are wrong.

It is using the correct number, but the wrong text, combined to form "Figure 2" that doesn't actually exist in the document.

Swapping the order of `\usepackage` lines makes no difference.

[image: Strange output, contains "Figure" in three links and "Equation" in one, exactly opposite the source material]

What's the right way to use `\label` on `\begin{dmath}` and `\begin{dgroup}` environments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment `dmath` of package `breqn` does not use `\refstepcounter` for the incrementation of the counter `equation`. Package `hyperref` hooks into `\refstepcounter` to add a hyper anchor as link target. Therefore your example uses the anchor before (`figure.1`) and you get the previous figure as link target.

Workaround: The following example patches `\eq@setnumber` to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\eq@setnumber{\stepcounter}{\refstepcounter}{}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \noexpand\eq@setnumber failed}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Something strange}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Something strange}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\begin{dmath}\label{addition}
1 + 1 = 2
\end{dmath}

I want to talk about \autoref{addition}, not \autoref{fig}.

\begin{equation}
\label{subtraction}
2 - 1 = 1
\end{equation}

And \autoref{subtraction} is not very interesting.  Let me speak of
\autoref{addition}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Funny thing was, it does get the counter from dmath, just the text in front is wrong. And chngctr does affect dmath numbering.

Comment: `dmaht` sets `\@currrentlabel` manually instead of using `\refstepcounter`. Thus it ignores `hyperref` completely. `\autoref` uses the anchor name to get the counter, the last anchor name was `figure.1`, thus `\autoref` sets the prefix for figures.

Comment: On further investigation, it looks like you're right that the hyperlink actually was going to the figure prior to the equation (usually they were on the same page making it hard to detect).  Your `patchcmd` fixes both the text and the behavior.  Thanks.